# Search for a binary number in a set that contains a 1 or 0 in certain locations

Tags: php

I have an array of strings (zeros and ones) in a format similar to the following:

> [01100101],[10010000],[00000001]...and so on (all the same length, there's about 30 entries)

I'd like to be able to search these numbers using a search similar to "0xxxx01". The search, in this case, would return the first and third string.

What would be the best way to go about doing this? I'm in the middle of learning PHP, an answer in that format would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on top of the answer posted by @George Lund (you need to use . instead of X):

```
$arr = array('01100101','10010000','00000001');

$result = preg_grep("/0.....01/", $arr);

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/140934)

Comment: Awesome!I was hoping there was something simple like this. I won't have the chance to try it for a while. I'll accept the answer, for the time being. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score -1):

Using strings for binary data seems very inefficient, but as stated your problem can be dealt with using regular expressions..

```
$a = array('01100101','10010000','00000001');
$r = array_filter($a, function($v) {
  return preg_match('/0.....01/', $v);
});
var_dump($r);
```

So use dots where in your example you used x.

Hope that gives you a couple of useful PHP functions to go learn about anyway, good luck!

Comment: This appears just to be a suggestion so it should fall under the comment category.

Comment: Nonsense, the OP isn't expecting a complete program as clearly they will be building something larger. It's not a suggestion, it is working code. (Though the OP got the number of X's wrong by the look of it and I didn't spot that.)

Comment: _It's not a suggestion, it is working code._ You serious ? Well, it threw me errors.  You don't even have the patience to explain what your code does , IMHO , this is seriously an **incomplete** post and leads to nowhere.

Comment: There you go. Sorry, but I'm sure the OP could have figured out what was wrong, certainly someone with your rep should have been able to!

Comment: FYI , Rep has nothing to with the knowledge. Removed my downvote.

Comment: Fair enough, apologies: I was a somewhat grumpy at getting the initial down vote that had no useful feedback -- which was nothing to do with you at all.

Answer (score -1):

#### Explanation :

- Initialize your array with all those elements.
- Assign the pattern
- The `$xcount` holds the number of `X` occurence in the pattern. (This is used at the end)
- The `$delim` holds the starting and endpoint values.

Now loop through the original array and do a `preg_match_all()` to grab all matches between the two delimiters, the perfect match is the one which the length equal to `X` that is the `$xcount` variable which we previously determined.

---

```
<?php
$arr=array('01100101','10010000','00000001');
$patrn = '0XXXXX01';
$xcount = array_count_values(str_split($patrn))['X']; //5
$delim  = explode('X',implode('',str_split($patrn)));
$end = count($delim)-1;
foreach($arr as $v)
{
    preg_match_all("/$delim[0](.*)$delim[$end]/", $v, $matches);
    if(strlen($matches[1][0])==$xcount)
    {
        echo $v."<br>";
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
01100101
00000001
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/140911)</kbd>

Comment: I'm downvoting only because your answer appears to basically do the same as mine, but in many more lines of code! I've no idea why my answer was downvoted.

Comment: @GeorgeLund, Try to post a working code instead of telling the OP to _Hope that gives you a couple of useful PHP functions to go learn about anyway, good luck!_ Yours was downvoted as it should really be a comment.